# Input not focusing the first time key is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make an `input` appear (go from `display: none` to `display: block`) when `/` is pressed. Then the `input` should be focused (the cursor should be in the `input`).

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, ChangeEvent } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function App() {
  const [inputValue] = useState("");
  const [isInputFocused, setIsInputFocused] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  function handleInputChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    // some code
  }

  function handleInputBlur(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setIsInputFocused(false);
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
    if (event.key === "/") {
      event.preventDefault();
      setIsInputFocused(true);
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();

    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="keys" className={isInputFocused ? "active" : "inactive"}>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onBlur={handleInputBlur}
        value={inputValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(<App />);
```

This works as expected ... except the first time you press `/`, the `input` appears, but it's not focused (the cursor doesn't jump to the `input`). You have to press `/` again for the input to be focused.

Why is this? And how to change the code so that the `input` is focused the first time you press `/`?

Live example:

[image: Edit React Input Focus]

Comment: `return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };` Why do you need this?

Comment: @DreamBold To remove the listener. I thought it was a good practice to remove listeners when React components unmount. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-remove-event-listener

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-focus-forked-50t8yz?file=/src/index.tsx you add the listen and then remove it immediately, which is not necessary, I guess

Comment: The SetStateAction is async, the input is not in DOM yet when you try focusing it.

Comment: @ghybs How can I get around that?

Comment: @DreamBold To be honest, I don't know. But many people suggest cleaning up listeners after the component doesn't need them anymore: https://dev.to/marcostreng/how-to-really-remove-eventlisteners-in-react-3och

Comment: @DreamBold the return with removeEventListener is not executed immediately. This is the `React.useEffect` syntax for cleanup https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ghybs said, setting state is async, so the actual re-render will happen at the next tick.

This means you can't immediately expect the `input` field to be rendered as soon as you set the `isInputFocused` state to true.

It needs to wait till the next tick.

Easiest way to wait till the next tick in React is using `setTimeout`:

```
setIsInputFocused(true);
setTimeout(() => {
  inputRef.current?.focus();
}, 0);
```

A more elegant solution is to wait for `isInputFocused` state change and apply the focus action:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isInputFocused) {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }
}, [isInputFocused]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it's not bad practice to use `useEffect` to solve this kind of situation?

Comment: It's good practice, and what `useEffect` was actually designed for. You can have as many `useEffect`s as you want in your component.

Comment: @alexchenco Anything still not clear? Or do you need any other solution? Otherwise, please accept the answer.